# Why can't I merge two vertices?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have modelled half of character and added Mirror modifier to it.

Now there are 2 vertices in the bottom that refuse to connect.

First, I can't move them by X axis towards each other for some reason. Also, I've tried every option that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> has to offer but it didn't do anything.

P.S Also if anyone knows why the shading is so massive, that would be helpful too.

[image: screenshot of mirrored character with unmergeable vertices]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong order in the modifiers stack.
Move the mirror modifier to the top to make merging of the corner vertices possible.

Answer (score 4):

Merge wont work because you are selecting only one vertex, that shows up as two because of the mirror modifier, and if you try to merge it it will merge itself = nothing will happen. To join them properly just select one of the vertices and move it toward the center using the red arrow(x axis).

The blue/dark shading in your object is probably because of inverted normals, to fix it select all the vertices, press space and type "flip normals" then hit enter

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick reply. Second, I've tried moving through the x axis, believe me. This is the first thing that didn't work.

Comment: Ok I get it now, in the modifiers list, the mirror is applied after the subdivision, what you have to do is go to the header of the mirror modifier and click on the up arrow next to the X, to move it on top of the subdivision. Now you should be able to select the "original" bottom vertex and move it